# Display a single item from the Model in the same view as a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel, html-helper

I want to display a search result using this InstitutionName as a query, but instead of appearing in the resulting table repeatedly on every row, I just want to show it as a heading. I tried using DisplayFor but it always returns an error, I'm guessing because my model is an IEnumerable, but I don't know, I just put in DisplayNameFor temporarily to simulate the output I want to show, which should be the value of the property itself and not just the property name.

I've read about using a ViewModel but I just want to know if I can accomplish this with what I have right now.

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<SMOSystemv2.Models.Tender>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Tenders";
}

<h1>Tender History</h1>
<h2>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName)</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Compendium.Qualification.Title)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Slots)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalAmount)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Compendium.Qualification.Title)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Slots)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)
            </td> 

        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Its not clear what you what the result to be. Do you want the value of `InstitutionName` to appear in the first row of your table only (and just show a blank table cell for all subsequent rows)?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I want the value of  InstitutionName as a heading/title found in <h2> and not in the tables at all, since the value of InstitutionName will be the same across all rows

Comment: Then you could use `<h2>@Model.First().Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName</h2>`, but it would be far better to use a view model containing a property for `Name`, and a property for the collection (which would be another view model containing properties for `Title`, `Slots` and `Total`)

Comment: I think `DisplayFor` used to render predefined text for properties using `EditorFor`, what about directly using `@Model` or using separate viewmodel properties to display headers? It's still unclear what you trying to do & what result you want to achieve.

Comment: @Model.First() is the answer that I am looking for as of the moment, but I'm still interested to learn how to use a ViewModel, I was thinking that my Models are already complicated as it is for fear of creating another table in my db so I was initially avoiding it, may I ask in what ways is it better?

Comment: View models are not related to data models (or EF). You put them in a separate folder (say `ViewModels`) and you project the results of your query into a collection of the view model.

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, not the question (I have rolled back your changes). Feel free to add you own answer and accept it to close this out.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, how can I credit them to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of display that I was initially looking for using @Model.First() as suggested, but implementing a ViewModel instead is highly recommended

```
@model IEnumerable<SMOSystemv2.Models.Tender>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tenders";
}

<h1>Tender History</h1>
<h2>@Model.First().Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Compendium.Qualification.Title)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Slots)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TotalAmount)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Semester)
        </th>
        <th nowrap>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateReceived)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Compendium.Qualification.Title)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Slots)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Semester)
            </td>
            <td nowrap>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateReceived)
            </td>

            <td nowrap>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This property returns the **first** option of the list or option selected as the **default**

[FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 @if(Model != null){
    <h2>@Model.FirstOrDefault().Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName</h2>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution:

```
<h2>@Html.DisplayNameFor(@Model.FirstOrDefault().Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName)</h2>
```

instead of

`<h2>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Compendium.Institution.InstitutionName)</h2>`

because you are using `@model IEnumerable<SMOSystemv2.Models.Tender>` at your code. The property `FirstOrDefault()` will give you the first value in the list as default value.